# How to clear all caches with Drush 9?

Tags: 8, drush

https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/cache/cache:clear/ this doesn't give any option to clear all caches. All you get is to choose from 0-7, old `drush cc all` or `cr all` are gone.

Eg.

```
root@dev:/var/www/example.com/htdocs# drush cc --cache-clear

 Choose a cache to clear:
  [0] Cancel
  [1] drush
  [2] theme-registry
  [3] router
  [4] css-js
  [5] render
  [6] plugin
  [7] bin
  [8] views
 > 7

 [success] 'bin' cache was cleared.
```

How to clear all options below with one command? I can't find it documented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To clear drupal caches using drush 9x use the following command:

```
drush cache:clear
```

Command aliases:

- `drush cc`
- `drush cache-clear`

To clear all caches you can use:

```
drush cache:rebuild
```

Command aliases:

- `drush cr`
- `drush rebuild`
- `drush cache-rebuild`